# Do I need two TableViewControllers?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to do the following: when a user opens this dog breed app an empty table with a search bar appears. When the user clicks on the search bar and enters the letter A, they will see breeds matching with the letter A/a. When the user clicks on a dog breed, that breed will be added to the empty table they saw before. Below is my code

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating {

    var dogBreeds = ["Corgi", "Beagle", "Maltese", "Poodle", "Dachshund"]
    var filteredDogs = [String]()
    var selectedDogs = [String]()

    var searchController: UISearchController!

    var resultsController = UITableViewController()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.resultsController.tableView.dataSource = self
        self.resultsController.tableView.delegate = self

        self.searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: self.resultsController)
        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar
        self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self

        self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        definesPresentationContext = true

        // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
        // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

        // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
        // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
    }

    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
        //filter through the Dogs array
        self.filteredDogs =  self.dogBreeds.filter { (breedName:String) -> Bool in
            if breedName.lowercased().contains(self.searchController.searchBar.text!.lowercased()) {
                return true
            }
            else {
                return false
            }
        }
        // update the table view
        self.resultsController.tableView.reloadData()
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if tableView == self.tableView{
            return self.selectedDogs.count
        }
        else {
            return self.filteredDogs.count
        }
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell()
        if tableView == self.tableView {
            if !selectedDogs.isEmpty {
                cell.textLabel?.text = self.selectedDogs[indexPath.row]
            }
        }
        else {
            cell.textLabel?.text = self.filteredDogs[indexPath.row]
        }
        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        selectedDogs.append(self.filteredDogs[indexPath.row])
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

I am at the point where I am able to click on the a dog breed, Corgi for example, and it gets added to the TableView but I get an error when I click on Corgi. I am assuming it is because I am using 1 TableView for my search and Tableview population and calling TableView didSelectRowAt applies to the entire table and not just the filtered search. Also, how do I transition back to the tableview after a row has been clicked?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have this dispatch pattern in multiple places

```
if tableView == self.tableView {
    // Use behavior for the first view controller
} else {
    // Use behavior for the second view controller
}
```

you would probably be better off with two separate view controllers, each having the code that belongs to the table view controlled by it. This would improve readability of your code, even though the total length would go up slightly, because related blocks of code would be closer to each other.

Comment: @LampPost This depends on the situation a good deal, but when you see the same `if`/`else` pattern in multiple places, it's a good reason to think the controllers should be separated.

Answer (score 0):

Well having two table view controller means you have another long set of delegate and data source to take care of plus the passing around of data like search results. In your situation, it's very easy to finish the job using a single table view. You just need some simple tweak on separating selected array and filtered array.

Replace your

```
if tableView == self.tableView {

} else {

}
```

With

```
if searchController.searchBar.text != "" { 

} else {

}
```

In this case we are saying that, if you have some text in your search bar, display filtered results, otherwise display selected results. Then in your cell click listener:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    selectedDogs.append(self.filteredDogs[indexPath.row])
    searchController.searchBar.text = ""
    //This is also a good practice to remove text in search bar and then send user back to selected list.
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```